# adding Elasticsearch logging handler to Flask doesn't populate the Index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I want to integrate a logging handler into Flask so all flask logs are replicated inside Elasticsearch. To do this I created the following code to add the handler:

```
from flask import Flask
from cmreslogging.handlers import CMRESHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = CMRESHandler(hosts=[{'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9200}],
                           auth_type=CMRESHandler.AuthType.NO_AUTH,
                           es_index_name="test_logger")
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run()
```

However none of the logs are showing up in my Elasticsearch. I created the index manually.

Comment: Are you solluted a problem? Face a similar thing. No error, no 400 or 500 responces from ES. There is question what the reason: index, logging level or something more